# Why does the CSS not affect the header?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress project, and when i wrote everything by hand for a static HTML page, the CSS worked fine. Now when i do it in wordpress, it seems to not get my commands.

The header file is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simons sida</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/style.css' ?>">

</head>

<body>

<div id="ttr_header">
<h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
```

While the external CSS for that is

```
#ttr_header {
    padding: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 30px;
  }
```

The sidebar works properly, but the header doesn't get affected at all, so i don't get what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: headings have default styles that don't inherit from their parent, you have to target them specifically if you want to override them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    #ttr_header h1 {
        padding: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #1abc9c;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="ttr_header">
<h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Changing the selector might help as you are targeting the div instead of the header:

```
#ttr_header h1 {
    padding: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the h1 selector, but it seems to still not work.
Even if i write only h1, without ttr_header, it does not work.
I tried changing the div to a header tag too, and changing the css to only header, still no luck.